# How to find latest MD5, KEY and VERSION when using Yowsup

Tags: yowsup

I have seen issues where registering with whatsapp server sometimes fails when using yowsup with old_version error ([Yowsup - old_version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877803/yowsup-old-version-error)). I understand this is due to whatsapp upgrading itself, what is a good way to find latest MD5, KEY and VERSION that whatsapp uses so that yowsup can register without an issue.

Comment: @slondono can you please comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use this site:
https://coderus.openrepos.net/whitesoft/whatsapp_scratch

This site provides the MD5, key and the version.

Comment: What does each of values corresponding to key mean in json file generated?

Answer (score 1):

follow these 3 simple steps:

```
git remote add jlguardi https://github.com/jlguardi/yowsup.git
git pull jlguardi Android_2.12.440
git merge jlguardi/Android_2.12.440
sudo python setup.py install
```

This should solve the issue

Comment: So, this method doesnt work anymore. glguardi doesnt have Android respo anymore! Any work around?